# Form problem with windows scale layout settings

Tags: scale, display, delphi-xe8

I have an application developed with DelphiXE8, when the windows11 or win10 scale layout settings are 125% and I minimize the secondary form that is normally found at the bottom left above the statusBar, it is not seen because it is positioned off the screen.
[image: I don't see the form minimized]

scale layout settings are 100% and I minimize, the result is correct
[image: I see the form minimized correctly]

How can I fix?